# removing all animation from the layer of a superview

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have a super view called `OverLayIntroView` which has few subviews and I have added animation to those subviews.

My question is if I call `[self.OverLayIntroView.layer removeAllAnimations];` will it remove animation from the subviews as well?

Comment: What is so wrong with trying for yourself? This should be super easy to just call the method and see what happens, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't.

From CALayer's documentation on removeAllAnimations:
"Remove all animations attached to the layer."
Meaning that animations attached to sublayers will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this static method

```
+ (void)setAnimationsEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
```

For Disable/Enable Animation of `UIView`. As you said this will remove animation of the layer.